# Comma throwing errors in table creation in PGadmin4

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl

While trying to generate a table in PGadmin, I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
LINE 3:     "ID" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT,    
                                         ^
```

Why doesn't it like the comma? This is the sql generated by PGadmin, it's strange it does not like it's own sql.

```
CREATE TABLE public.email_list
(
    "ID" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT,
    "FIRST NAME" "char",
    "LAST NAME" "char",
    "EMAIL" "char",
    "TITLE" "char",
    "LOCATION" "char",
    "COMPANY WEBSITE" "char",
    "COMPANY TYPE" numeric,
    "DATE ADDED" timestamp with time zone,
    "LAST CONTACT DATE" date,
    "STATUS CODE" "char",
    CONSTRAINT "ID" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.email_lists
    OWNER to postgres;
```

Comment: You did not supply a `DEFAULT` value. FYI, you do not need to quote the type names, so `char` instead of "char". Also you would be better of with `varchar` not `char`, if for no other reason then `char` without a length will default to a length of 1.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: [Don't use char](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, actually I missed this also. The OP is using `"char"` which is an internal type and even more limited then `char`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When first look at your query i saw something look not fit, here i show how I fixed it.

```
CREATE TABLE public.email_list
(
    "ID" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT, <<-- You have to set DEFAULT follow with some value e.g : DEFAULT 0, or u can remove the DEFAULT keyword instead.
    "FIRST NAME" "char",
    "LAST NAME" "char",
    "EMAIL" "char",
    "TITLE" "char",
    "LOCATION" "char",
    "COMPANY WEBSITE" "char",
    "COMPANY TYPE" numeric,
    "DATE ADDED" timestamp with time zone,
    "LAST CONTACT DATE" date,
    "STATUS CODE" "char",
    CONSTRAINT "ID" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
)
```

Hope this can help solve the problem.

Comment: This just creates another issue, the one where all the "char" columns are turned into a single byte type and anything you enter into them will be truncated to a single character.  Pretty sure the OP does not want that. "char" is a  internal type and should not be used in a user table.  See [Character types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html) Table 8.5. Special Character Types.